# Generating a formula from Google Script when a Column is filled

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When Col3 is filled, I'd like to generate automatically the formula `=M%s-SUM(AD%s;AS%s;BH%s;BW%s)` and `=SUM(R%s;V%s;Z%s)`. My code is working for the vlookup formula, but not for the sums.

```
  if (r.getRow() == lastRow && r.getColumn() == 3){
          event.range.offset(0,8).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;6;false);"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // Sellsy estimate number vlookup
          event.range.offset(0,9).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;4;false);"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // local currency vlookup
          event.range.offset(0,10).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;5;false);"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // approved cost vlookup
          event.range.offset(0,11).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=M%s-SUM(AD%s;AS%s;BH%s;BW%s)',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // remaining to be invoiced formula
          event.range.offset(0,28).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=SUM(R%s;V%s;Z%s)',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // sum Q1 formula

   }
```

Does any one have an idea?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more complete answer the provide a more complete example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();

  if (e.range.rowStart==sh.getLastRow() && e.range.columnStart==3){
    e.range.offset(0,8).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;6;false);"To complete")',e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart));
    e.range.offset(0,9).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;4;false);"To complete")',e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart));
    e.range.offset(0,10).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;5;false);"To complete")',e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart));
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==sh.getLastRow() && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value) {      
    e.range.offset(0,11).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=M%s-SUM(AD%s;AS%s;BH%s;BW%s)',e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart)); // remaining to be invoiced formula
    e.range.offset(0,28).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=SUM(R%s;V%s;Z%s)',e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart)); // sum Q1 formula
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper. Thank you for your help. I understand the const you created and I've updated my code with your comment, but this is still not working. Unfortunately the formula I'm looking for isn't created when I run my code. I want to create a sum formula in specific cells when I edit Col3 of my sheet. The code is working for the `vlookup` formula, but not for the sum and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. I had to add `event.range.rowStart` as many times there are different columns I think.

```
 if (event.range.rowStart==sh.getLastRow() && event.range.columnStart==3){
    event.range.offset(0,8).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;6;false);"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart));
    event.range.offset(0,9).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;4;false);"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart));
    event.range.offset(0,10).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFNA(vlookup($E%s;Overview!F:K;5;false);"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart));
    event.range.offset(0,11).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFERROR((M%s-(AD%s+AS%s+BH%s+BW%s));"To complete")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // remaining to be invoiced formula
    event.range.offset(0,27).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=(R%s+V%s+Z%s)',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart)); // sum Q1 formula
```